# Изменённые пиксели картинки не отображаются

Tags: python, изображения, numpy, pillow

Я с numpy знаком довольно бегло, прошу помочь. Я хотел написать программу, которая создаёт гифку крутящегося куба. После каждой итерации цикла, которая рисует куб под определённым углом, надо очищать картинку. Я это делаю с помощью numpy.zeros, однако после того, как изображение заполняется белым, изменения на нём дальше не отображаются. Вот код:

```
frames_amount = 100
period = 4
FPS = frames_amount / period
dA = math.pi * 2 / frames_amount
frames = []

array = np.zeros((Cw, Ch, 3), dtype = "uint8")
array[:] = 255

for i in range(frames_amount):
    alpha = i * dA
    DrawCube(alpha)
    frames.append(deepcopy(img))
    print(i+1, "%", sep = '')
    img.show()
    img = Image.fromarray(array)

frames[0].save("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\3D\\Rasterization\\spinning_cube.gif", save_all = True, append_images = frames[1:], optimize = True, duration = round(1000/FPS), loop = 0)
```

Код DrawCube приводить не буду, слишком много кода получится, скажу только, что она рисует куб под заданным углом, используя низкоуровневую функцию putpixel. DrawCube использует функцию, которая отрисовывает линии и которая импортируется из другого проекта. В самом вызове функции используется глобальная переменная img. В первой итерации цикла он показывает всё нормально, а после первого выполнения команды img = Image.fromarray(array) он показывает лишь пустую белую картинку, а не куб, повёрнутый на маленький угол.

Comment: Очень странный код в целом. Но вообще вы же сами заполняете всё белым сразу после zeros вот этой строкой array[:] = 255, ну и дальше если вы где-то ещё не меняете array (а в этом коде вы его не меняете), то вот это белое и пропадает в img = Image.fromarray(array)

Comment: Да, я знаю). Я уже решил проблему, хотя на вопрос не смог ответить. Я просто рисую те же самые рёбра куба, только белым цветом, когда мне надо очистить холст